# Why aren't custom API endpoints shown in my Azure Mobile Apps Swagger UI?

Tags: azure, express, swagger, azure-mobile-services

I have followed the Microsoft sample of how to create a custom API. So I have added this line to `app.js`:

```
mobile.api.import('../api/date');
```

Then in `api/date.js` I have:

```
var dates = {
    get: function (req, res, next) {
        var date = { currentTime: Date.now() };
        res.status(200).type('application/json').send(date);
    }
};

module.exports = dates;
```

So I can successfully GET `http://localhost:3000/api/date`, however, only my default table operations show up in the Swagger UI, how do I get this to contain my new endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger endpoint only contains information for the tables.  See issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/303